# Consuming an EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, java

Can I consume EJBs made with Java EE 6 (JDK6) in an application made with JDK 1.4?

I am sorry but I am very new to EJBs and just trying to evaluate the possibilities of using Java EE 6 in one of our services.

Can I  consume the EJB like shown in http://openejb.apache.org/hello-world.html from my JDK 4 compatible app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run a Java EE 6 Application Server in a JDK 1.4, **but** you can execute an independent application in JDK 1.4 and **consume** (invoke remotely) EJBs **from** whatever Java EE Application Server (included version 6 ones) retrieving a reference to it by JNDI (as usual).

The remote communication (behind scenes) is done via RMI, which is compatible between JDK1.4 and JDK6.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I thought, if you don't mind can you please shed a little light on how can I remotely invoke ejb method in JDK 4 java class? I will appreciate if you can give me a pointer to a step by step tutorial or something. With JDK6 I could create the EJB in a snap but am not able to create the client with JDK 4

Comment: You are welcome. In the link you pasted in your question you have a fairly good step by step. Anyway, if you need more, I suggest you to open a new question for that (the comments are quite limited). And I would ask you to consider to mark the answer as accepted if you think it answers your question :). Thanks!

Comment: I have posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117473/ejb-consumption-in-jdk1-4 Can you help me there?