# Ejb consumption in JDK1.4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss6.x

As a postlude to [Consuming an EJB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675400/consuming-an-ejb) question. I have created an ejb on JBOSS AS 6.0 and am consuming it in a java client using the following code.

```
private ServiceLocator(String host, String principal, String creadentials) throws NamingException {
        Properties env = new Properties();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,
                "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://" + host);
        System.out.println("jnp://" + host);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principal);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, creadentials);
        env.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "org.jboss.security.jndi.JndiLoginInitialContextFactory");
        InitialContext ct = new InitialContext(env);
        cachedStructSpeechRemote = (StructSpeechRemote) ct.lookup("eCWServicesEAR/StructSpeechService/remote-com.ecw.ejb.StructSpeechRemote");
    }
```

The consumer uses JBOSS-all-client.jar present in client folder of JBoss AS6.0. I am not able to use the same code with JDK1.4 because the jar is not JDK 1.4 compatible. I have also tried to get the jar file form the older distribution of JBoss AS but than it does not work with the newer distribution of the server:(
Is there a way to write an EJB consumer which is JDK version independent (May be also vendor independent!) and can work in all JDKs ranging from 1.4 to 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I would expose the EJB on JBoss as a web service to be able to call it from any jvm. Otherwise you can try to find more info here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/EJBTHREE-1029?focusedCommentId=12371962

Comment: That's what I am doing right now and it was very easy to do with just one annotation. But I want to use EJB as it will save a great deal of time in XML marshalling and unmarshalling.